# Creating a JavaScript drag and drop editor for kids, want to include JSHint to check syntax - how would I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a Drag & Drop JavaScript editor for some school kids:

https://jsfiddle.net/xfjd6beo/

I am having problems doing two things:

1. I'd like to include the library JSHint to validate the JavaScript in the textarea.
2. I want to also include another variables list on the right hand side, that is pulled from another JavaScript file called Variables.js.

The contents of Variables.js is simply a list of variables:

```
var HelloWorld = Hello World;
var Cat = Thomas;
```

The idea is that on the left are all the default statements like if/else and on the right is a list of variables that the kids can drag and drop to product code like:

```
function helloCat(){

 alert(Cat);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve the two?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer because I don't have so much time:

1. According to [JSHINT doc](http://jshint.com/docs/api/) just use the `JSHINT()` function :

   > ## `JSHINT( source, options, predef )`
   >
   > Parameters:
   >
   > - **source**
   >
   >   - *Description*: The input JavaScript source code Type: string or
   >       an array of strings (each element is interpreted as a newline)
   >   - *Example*: `JSHINT(["'use strict';", "console.log('hello, world!');"]);`
   > - **options**
   >
   >   - Description: The linting options to use when analyzing the
   >       source code Type: an object whose property names are the desired
   >       options to use and whose property values are the configuration values
   >       for those properties.
   >   - *Example*: `JSHINT(mySource, { undef: true });`
   > - **predef**
   >
   >   - *Description*: variables defined outside of the current file; the
   >       behavior of this argument is identical to the globals linting option
   >       Type: an object whose property names are the global variable
   >       identifiers and whose property values control whether each variable
   >       should be considered read-only
   >   - *Example*: `JSHINT(mySource, myOptions, {jQuery: false });`
2. You cannot export variables from a script, the best way to do this would be to store your variables as a json file, and then to load your variables via an ajax call ([see jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) for example...